# How to use the headers of a data frame for a dropdown?

Tags: python, plotly

I have this `df`

```py
df = pd.read_csv("00001234.csv")
```

and the `head` is:

```py
file_name = "00001234.csv"

with open(file_name, "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = reader(csv_file)
    head = next(csv_reader)
    print("head:")
    print(", ".join(head))
    print("Values:")

    for row in csv_reader:
        print(", ".join(row))

print(head)
```

which shows this result:

```py
['Player', 'Chips Won', 'Hands', 'WWSF', 'WSD', 'Call R & WSD']
```

I have this `Dropdown`:

```py
dropdown1_scatter_chart = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="dropdown1_scatter_chart",
    options=[{"value": label, "label": label} for label in df.head],
    value=df.head[0],
    className="six columns",
    clearable=False
)
```

but it is wrong because of this error:

```py
options=[{"value":label, "label":label} for label in df.head],
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

How can I use the header to choose in the dropdown?

Comment: Instead of `for label in df.head`, try with `for label in df.columns`.

Comment: great thanks ... that solved that error